# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component, while using MaterialDialog component

Tags: android, react-native

There are other solutions available but they are not related to my problem.
I do not not have text outside the component

```
 import { MaterialDialog } from 'react-native-material-dialog';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);[enter image description here][1]
    this.state = {
       visible: true,
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MaterialDialog
          title={"Use Google's Location Service?"}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={() => this.setState({ visible: false })}
          onCancel={() => this.setState({ visible: false })}>
          <Text>
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous
            location data to Google, even when no apps are running.
          </Text>
        </MaterialDialog>;
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated !! Thanks to this wonderful community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove semicolons
change

```
</MaterialDialog>;
```

to

```
</MaterialDialog>
```

Comment: Hey can you look at the following question also: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943759/i-was-to-implement-custompicker-in-my-functional-component-in-react-native